# Comparing data between two dates

Tags: excel, comparison

I want to compare the data for 2 dates for eg data of today and yesterday.

I want a chart in excel that should always display data for today and yesterday. The chart should update automatically and the comparison show should be for the current date and day before(yesterday).

Comment: Don't really understand your problem, but guess you can use =`TODAY()` and `=TODAY()-1`

Comment: create a chart, then set the filter to dates between TODAY() - 1 and TODAY()

Comment: Thanks both of you... my query is I need to show data for only current day and yesterday for eg 19th May and 20th May and tomorrow it should show 20th May and 21st May and so on.  Only 2 days data in chart.